# Deploying Laravel 5 in Go Daddy Plesk

Tags: deployment, laravel-5, web-hosting, plesk

Im having problems deploying my Laravel 5 Project on Go Daddy Plesk . I'm getting Internal 500 Error. Here's the folder structure.

```
/Root Directory
/app
/boostrap
/config
/database
/storage
/resources
/vendor
/httpdocs
   index.php
   /css
   /js
```

Then my server.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylorotwell@gmail.com>
 */

$uri = urldecode(
    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);

// This file allows us to emulate Apache's "mod_rewrite" functionality from the
// built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel
// application without having installed a "real" web server software here.
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/httpdocs'.$uri))
{
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/httpdocs/index.php';
```

So as you can see, I deleted my public folder in my laravel and transfered all the public contents inside httpdocs but I already changed the path on server.php
did I missed anything?

My .htaccess under httpdocs

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please update question with server OS name and PHP error which trigger error 500,

Comment: Also make sure you have using PHP version 5.3 or above.

Comment: Hi! Did you work it out? I have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

the one reason is you wouldn't have set permission for your public folder. Another you would need 5.5+ php version in order to make Laravel work. First set permission and try changing php version. I strongly believe this would work.